# How to create an array of character arrays in c++? (only using iostream)

Tags: c++, arrays, char, iostream

I am very new to c++.

Say I have this:

```
char arrOne[10];
char arrTwo[10];
char arrThree[10];
```

How can I create an array where each element in the array holds a character array like above?

The goal is to be able to call upon the index of the array of arrays to grab one of these character arrays when needed.

Keep in mind. I can ONLY use iostream.

Comment: An array of arrays? An array of pointers? Or better yet, an array of [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) objects.

Comment: Like I said I can't use string.h I can only use iostream. I don't know a whole lot about arrays in c++. I know it involves pointers, that is why I need some guidance here.

Comment: @itdoesntwork I tried that and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: @Smartypants, Good thing `std::string` isn't in string.h. Arrays don't have to involve pointers, either. `std::array` is as good as any other array and has nothing to do with pointers.

Comment: I have to use character arrays instead of strings. It is part of the project description :/

Comment: Arrays and streams are unrelated, so saying you _need_ to use iostream for creating a multidimensional array is pretty much meaningless.

Comment: Alright, sorry about that. What I wanted to get across is that I didn't want to get answers like "why are you not just using strings?" or "just use this cool trick" because I have to do it at the most basic level. Also, why the down vote? It says plainly I am new to c++. So new people to programming get downvoted for their lack of knowledge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a char pointer array

```
char * array[3];

char arrOne[10]
char arrTwo[10]
char arrThree[10]

array[0] = arrOne;
array[1] = arrTwo;
array[2] = arrThree;
```

To access arrayOne ,for example, use array[0].

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think you need to use a for/while loop to access each element in an array
for example

```
char array[10] = "hello";

int i = 0;

while (i != '\0')
{
 if( array[i] = 'l')
 {
   array[i] = 'x';
 }
i++;
}
 cout <<"new array string" << array<<endl;
```